# NetBeans,Data Connectivity

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I had been trying to create a program based on data connectivity. The goal of this program is to take an input in string and save it in the back end.
The program out of nowhere suddenly started showing errors of not recognizing the declared variables ,like there was this TextField which i named as (variableName) "JT1" but during code it unrecognizable by the computer. Help me out.
Here are the screenshots.

Design with text fields

[image: Design with text fields]

Error in Coding

[image: Error in Coding]

Update:1
As soon as i add the ending curly bracket for "try" it stops recognizing them. The green color signifies that it does recognize them.But as soon as i add the closing bracket it starts to give me an error.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyTgt.png)

Comment: `The program out of nowhere suddenly started showing errors` What did you do before the IDE start giving problems?

Comment: I did nothing. I made some programs earlier they worked fine, recognized everything but now it does not.

Comment: Did you accidentally moved your folders/java files or deleted the package written on top of your java files?

Comment: I checked there are all the packages. I even tried new programs within the database. Some i created earlier work but the new ones do not.

Comment: I would only say everything happens for a reason. It is very unlikely your IDE is buggy. Reopen your IDE and project and create a new project and see whether it can access those variables. I'm sure there are tonnes of ways to test it.

Comment: I tried a new database.Something weird happened. The variable were recognized before the introduction of "try" statement.As soon i added "try"  statement the error reappeared. Any guesses?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to place a closing curly bracket or you placed an extra bracket, or maybe you enclosed your declared variables within the brackets. All is possible.

Comment: Got it! Just some misplaced curly brackets.

Comment: So my assumptions were correct right?

Answer (score 0):

isn't it necessary using ";" end of the Connection con= (Connection) line?

Comment: "No it is not". That is what my book says.

Comment: @The Pixilated Wizard The warnings which are at left should direct you. Have you tried them?

Comment: The Warning says "Cannot find Symbol". And offers an option of creating a particular class but that is not helping.

Comment: @The Pixilated Wizard I think you should examine this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm and form it again. For example, your Class.forname line is wrong as the example I sent.